# Distance moved by XR-controller in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality

I have been making a script in Unity that measures how far a player has moved in the real world using XRNodes like this for example with the right hand:
`InputTracking.GetLocalPosition(XRNode.RightHand)` 
at the start of the movement and then comparing it to the end position
Now I would like to get the distance moved, even if the player moved around in a circle.
Is the a method to do this with XRNodes? Measuring total distance moved during play?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, well, you could just simply sum it up every frame like

```c#
// Stores the overall moved distance
private float totalMovedDistance;

// flag to start and stop tracking
// Could also use a Coroutine if that fits you better
private bool track;

// Store position of last frame
private Vector3 lastPos;

public void BeginTrack()
{
    // reset total value
    totalMovedDistance = 0;
    
    // store first position
    lastPos = InputTracking.GetLocalPosition(XRNode.RightHand);

    // start tracking
    track = true;
}

public void EndTrack()
{
    // stop tracking
    track = false;

    // whatever you want to do with the total distance now
    Debug.Log($"Total moved distance in local space: {totalMovedDistance}", this);
}

private void Update()
{
    // If not tracking do nothing
    if(!track) return;

    // get current controller position
    var currentPos = InputTracking.GetLocalPosition(XRNode.RightHand);

    // Get distance moved since last frame
    var thisFrameDistance = Vector3.Distance(currentPos, lastPos);

    // sum it up to the total value
    totalMovedDistance += thisFrameDistance;

    // update the last position
    lastPos = currentPos;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I know it wasnt the best question, but got a bit stuck in my own head, always helpful to get some outside feedback